# "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" - Caused by mysqli::multi_query

Tags: php, mysqli, mysqli-multi-query

I am running multiple deletes through `mysqli::multi_query` and it is messing up the next query in line. The following error is being thrown.

```
Error - SQLSTATE HY000. 
Sql error: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

Do I need to somehow clear the multi query so it doesn't mess with my next query? What is the cause of this error?

And this is how I am running my multi query:

```
function deleteSomeTables($args) {
    $sql = 'delete 1;delete another;';
    if ($database->multi_query($sql)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am using a recent version of Xampp on windows 7

Answer (score 10):

By using [mysqli::multi_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) you are firing off queries, but you need to handle the results of those queries before you move on. The [documentation page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) describes the various ways of handling the results. Once handled, you will be able to perform other queries fine.

The error message you are encountering is actually explained a little better on the page for [mysqli::query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) (although bear in mind that mysqli::query would not return a result object in this instance, as you are doing a delete).

You could of course change multi_query to multiple single queries, I don't know what the pros/cons of each approach are.

Comment: So how do I clear the query, since I am not getting anything returned. You haven't actually told me anything that I didn't know already.

Comment: Something like... `do { $mysqli->use_result(); } while( $mysqli->next_result() )`

Answer (score 10):

This helped me to remove 'Commands out of sync' error:

```
do { 
    $mysqli_conn_obj->use_result(); 
}while( $mysqli_conn_obj->more_results() && $mysqli_conn_obj->next_result() );
```

Add this code just after calling multi_query, it will use the result sets and resolve the error.

Answer (score 1):

Seva's code will most likely fix your issue, if you're using procedural style like me, use this

```
do {
  if ($result = mysqli_store_result($connect)) {
    mysqli_free_result($result);
  }
} while (mysqli_next_result($connect));
```